# Double click on row in data grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, grid

I want to have function in WPF:Double click on row in Data Grid will show
cells in window. How can I do it that?I programm so but I never have double click event. Can somebody help me?
Thanks.

```
     <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left"Margin="14,55,0,46"
                Name="dataGridCustomers" Width="575" ItemsSource="  {Binding Path=LoadDataBinding}"
                CanUserResizeRows="False">




            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="dataGridCustomers_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>


            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DEPARTMENT_ID}" Header="DepartmentID" Width="100"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DEPARTMENT_NAME}" Header="Department name" Width="100"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=LOCATION}" Header="Location" Width="150"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you add your C# code where are your handler is?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

So, for instance, your XAML might look something like this:

```
<SomeControl  MouseDown="MyMouseDownHandler">
...
 </SomeControl>
```

code behind the click event..

```
private void MyMouseDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        //Handle double-click
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own dependency property DataGridDoubleClickProperty where you attach handler for DataGrid.MouseDoubleClick event

```
public static class Commands
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty DataGridDoubleClickProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DataGridDoubleClickCommand", typeof ( ICommand ), typeof ( Commands ),
                      new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(AttachOrRemoveDataGridDoubleClickEvent)));

  public static ICommand GetDataGridDoubleClickCommand(DependencyObject obj)
  {
    return (ICommand) obj.GetValue(DataGridDoubleClickProperty);
  }

  public static void SetDataGridDoubleClickCommand(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
  {
    obj.SetValue(DataGridDoubleClickProperty, value);
  }

  public static void AttachOrRemoveDataGridDoubleClickEvent(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
  {
    DataGrid dataGrid = obj as DataGrid;
    if ( dataGrid != null )
    {
      ICommand cmd = (ICommand) args.NewValue;

      if ( args.OldValue == null && args.NewValue != null )
      {
        dataGrid.MouseDoubleClick += ExecuteDataGridDoubleClick;
      }
      else if ( args.OldValue != null && args.NewValue == null )
      {
        dataGrid.MouseDoubleClick -= ExecuteDataGridDoubleClick;
      }
    }
  }

  private static void ExecuteDataGridDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
  {
    DependencyObject obj = sender as DependencyObject;
    ICommand cmd = (ICommand) obj.GetValue(DataGridDoubleClickProperty);
    if ( cmd != null )
    {
      if ( cmd.CanExecute(obj) )
      {
        cmd.Execute(obj);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

In your View you use Binding to map this DependencyProperty to Command

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource viewModel}">
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
        clr:Commands.DataGridDoubleClickCommand="{Binding DataGridDoubleClick}"
    />
</Grid>
```

DataGridDoubleClick is ICommand property in your ViewModel class

Comment: @leoleo Can you add your C# code where are your handler is?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe on PreviewMouseDoubleClick event.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDoubleClick" Handler="OnDoubleClick"/>
</Style>
```

Handler:

```
private void OnDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DoubleClick!");
}
```

Comment: I guess your handler doesn't work because MouseDoubleClick event is handled by DataGrid.
Routed event may be either bubble (from child to parent) or tunnel (from parent to child).
Any Preview event is tunnel event that allows you to handle it before DataGrid does.